# Why textmate not using a typical Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, textmate

I've clone a [Textmate](https://github.com/textmate/textmate) source code, and build it.
When I read some code of Textmate, I found that it's not using a typical Xcode project.
So, why is that? The cocoa framework of Apple seems not convenient for developing-not-using-Xcode.

I wonder is there some good work flow for develop cocoa apps on OS X?

Or they did it just want to let us know they're cool?

Answer (score 3):

Odgaard blogged about this in two parts:

http://sigpipe.macromates.com/2010/01/15/build-automation-part-1/

http://sigpipe.macromates.com/2010/01/23/build-automation-part-2/

Comment: Hi, I'm not saying which build system textmate use, I want to know the develop tools they're using or their workflow.

Comment: @Loki: On OS X, make defaults to cc, which was GCC back when those posts were written and is now Clang. If TextMate does anything differently, it's specified in the Makefile(s).